# How to check NSDictionary values are nil in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdictionary

I have one NSDictionary and in that dictionary keys and values are dynamically added.Now I want to check if any value is nil then set empty string for that key.How can I check this? Now I am checking this using conditions but, Is there any simple way to check nil or empty values.Please help me,Thanks

Comment: Please post some code ! what have you done ?

Answer (score 2):

`NSDictionary` does not hold `nil` values for its keys.

If you want to test the presence/absence of a specific key's value, you can use `-objectForKey:`. The method returns `nil` if the key/value pair is absent.

For "empty values", you will have to expand on what is considered an empty value in the context of your program (e.g. some people use `NSNull` to indicate an empty value, or if you are working with strings as values an empty string).

Answer (score 0):

For any key you haven’t set a value for, your dictionary will return `nil` from `-objectForKey:`—in other words, if nothing’s set for a given key, that key doesn’t exist in the dictionary.

That said, it sounds like you have a list of keys that you’d like to ensure have a placeholder value in the dictionary, with that placeholder value being an empty string. For that, you’d want to do something like this:

```
- (void)addPlaceholdersForKeys:(NSArray *)keys toDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary {
    for (id key in keys) {
        if ([dictionary objectForKey:key] == nil) {
            [dictionary setObject:@"" forKey:key];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSDictionary` and other `collections` cannot contain `nil` values. But it must store a [null](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/index.html) value. You can check it like that:-

```
if (dictionary[key] == [NSNull null]) {
    [dictionary setObject:@"" forKey:key];
}
```

For more refer sample code:-

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:@"test" forKey:@"key1"];
[dict setObject:@"test1" forKey:@"key2"];
[dict setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"key3"];
NSLog(@"%@",dict);
if (dict[@"key3"]==[NSNull null])
{
  [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"key3"];
  NSLog(@"%@",dict);
}
```

Output:-

Before setting empty value:-

```
{
    key1 = test;
    key2 = test1;
    key3 = "<null>";
}
```

---

After setting empty value:-

```
{
    key1 = test;
    key2 = test1;
    key3 = "";
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you can do like this by `looping through` the `dictionary`

```
NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];
for(NSString *key in keys)
{
    if ([dictionary objectForKey:key] == NULL)
    {
        [dictionary setObject:@"" forKey:key];
    }
}
```

Comment: "NSDictionary does not hold nil values for its keys." = the `if` body will never execute